# How to get params from route to other screen?

Tags: flutter

I would like to ask you for advice there.

I am new at developing Flutter and I have an issue there which I cant seem to resolve yet.

Currently I am using Fluro Plugin for routing.

In **main.dart** I define the routes:

```
router.define('joke/:id', handler: new Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
return new Joke();
}));
```

After this I push this route with params to my **home.dart**.

```
onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'joke/' + '${document.documentID}'),
```

I am trying to get the generated parameter to the **joke.dart**

Can you please advice me how to get this done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

according to the [documentation](https://github.com/theyakka/fluro) you access the values from the params

```
router.define('joke/:id', handler: new Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
return new Joke(params["id"][0]);
```

Assuming you will be passing the value (in this case the documentId) into the Joke class via a constructor arg

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

I am trying to take the arguments from the class ( please see the attached image )

The result I get is:
Receiver: Instance of 'Joke' .

https://image.ibb.co/dMhM8J/flutter_screenshot.png

Comment: Solved. 
I just had to reboot the application

Comment: @CvetanKaradjov Please accept the answer so people can see that it works.